# Debugging jQuery code: How to debug without getting lost inside the jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

We have a mid-size web-app evenly written in MVC.NET/WebAPI and Backbone.Marionette. So, it's fair to say we spend sizable amounts of time at the Chrome and Firebug debug consoles.

Whenever a bug creeps into the code, and we just can't pinpoint exactly were it's coming from, it spawns a familiar nightmare.

1. Place your breakpoint at some reasonable point (like a function header that looks suspicious)
2. Refresh the page
3. Pray that none of the descendants of the function call any jQuery
4. If indeed we've been pulled into the hole, slowly `Step Into` and `Step Out Of` jQuery functions until my desired function is back in scope
5. Don't forget to breakpoint along the way so that if I `Over Step` a function that finally pulls me back in, I can start over from that point
6. Don't panic

This just seems to me like a major speed-bump. Do I really care how jQuery parses a selector? How it maps a function to my variable? Maybe, but in the *default* case, I certainly don't. I'm just trying to get my variable through the method chain to see what comes out the other end. If something breaks, I probably care about *why* it broke, but more likely, I'd rather read up on its usage and implement it correctly. I don't care enough to track it through reams of jQuery code.

Now, I understand this is the nature of the browser-loaded-interpretative-language beast that JavaScript is. I'm starting to wonder though, if we've reached a certain maturity level  where we can assume that the average developer bug does not require deep inspection of the "standard" (jQuery, Require, REST, you name it) libraries the script was built upon to be resolved.

Or more, precisely, to ASK A QUESTION, is there a debugger that lets me smoothly chart the functionality of my code, with as many callbacks as my code may have, without tangling me into code from "standard" libraries (assuming I tell the debugger what these libraries are)? Is there something out there smart enough to automatically navigate, say, jQuery code, and inject the focus back into my function, if my code gets pulled into the jQuery maze?

And ( please don't post this as Answer ;), but does anyone out there share my frustration, or am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Why are you stepping into the jQuery functions in the first place? Why not step over those calls? Or step out immediately if you accidentally step in? Do you have break-on-all-exceptions turned on (rather than break-on-uncaught-exceptions)?

Comment: @IanHenry The problem is that, it's sometimes unavoidable to step into jQuery. A simplistic example: **How do you debug the this function**: `#('.someClass').on('click', function () { /*Debug me*/ });`?

Comment: If you want to debug what is inside the event handle, you can just set a breakpoint inside the event handler. It doesn't work if its all on one line. You can also add "debugger;" in your code and it will start debugging there when hit. If you have a specific example I can post an answer as to how you would debug that situation, but each debugging scenario is different.

Comment: @Seabiscuit I would add a breakpoint inside the callback. Actually, because I'm lazy, I would add a [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement inside the callback. `$('.someClass').on('click', function (e) { debugger; /*Debug me*/ });`

Comment: Just make sure to remove the debugger statement before checking it in!

Comment: @IanHenry Fair enough. I don't doubt that there numerous workarounds. I'm asking if there's a technology out there that identifies the issue, and acts like a smart debugger.

Comment: Not that I have ever heard of, but I don't think you need one either. Unless there is either a bug in jquery or in your use of jquery, you wont need to step in to the jquery code. The formatting of your code and where you set your breakpoints is what it is all about.

Comment: You've sort of asked three different questions: how to debug a client app effectively, is there a library-aware debugger, and "does anyone share my frustration or am I missing something fundamental." I don't see debugging the code that you're interested in (as opposed to library code) as a workaround, it's sort of the answer to question 1. To question 2, I haven't heard of any, but I don't see the motivation for such a tool. And to question 3: I think that if you're stepping into library code (when you're not trying to debug the library), you've done something wrong.

Comment: I guess in order to answer, we need to have a better understand of what you mean by "it's sometimes unavoidable to step into jQuery," as that runs contrary to my experiences with client-side web development. In what scenarios do you find yourself forced to step into jQuery?